# Jquery: how to skip first element time

Tags: jquery, loops, element, repeat, skip

in this code snippet, i want to decrease (skip) the time of the first element because it takes a long time to appear on the screen (10000), is it possible ?!

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        var i = 0;
        setInterval(
        function() {
             $('.handler').html(i + "<br />");
             i = (++i) % 3;
        }
        , 10000);
    }
);
```

the result of this code:

```
screen empty
1
2
3
1
2
3
and so on ...
```

Thanks to @aTo

Comment: Add `1` to your HTML element and change `var i = 0;` to `var i = 1;`

Comment: I meant add `1` manually to your element and start from 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to declare the timer function first, and call it just once, before starting the `setInterval`:

```
var i = 0;
function timer() {
     $('.handler').html(i + "<br />");
     i = (i + 1) % 3;
}

timer();
setInterval(timer, 10000);
```

Comment: did you leave the above inside your `$(function() { ... })` block?

Comment: @SPrince note that I changed your increment line - it's not good practise to use an increment operator on the same variable that you're assigning.

Answer (score 2):

Put your code in a function, run the function on pageload and then use an interval to run the function every ten seconds:

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;

    go();
    setInterval(go, 10000);

    function go() {
       $('.handler').html(i + "<br />");
       i = (++i) % 3;
    }
});
```